# Accediendo a elementos padres del DOM - Refactorización

Tags: javascript, refactoring

**Me surge** la siguiente duda. En ocasiones no tan frecuentes he accedido a elementos padres con JavaScript usando `parentNode`. Cuando se acede al padre de un elemento el código JavaScript seria así:

```
let element= document.getElementById("btn");
element.parentNode;
```

El código se complica si quiero acceder al elemento padre en un nivel 8, el código seria así:

```
let element= document.getElementById("btn");
element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
```

El código anterior muestra que se necesita escribir 8 veces parentNode para acceder 8 niveles arriba del elemento seleccionado. La cuestión es como podría refactorizar este ultimo código y hacerlo mas sencillo?

una forma de refactorizar esto seria así:

```
let element= document.getElementById("btn");
let p1= element.parentNode;
let p2= p1.parentNode;
let p3= p2.parentNode;
let p4= p3.parentNode;
let p5= p4.parentNode;
let p6= p5.parentNode;
let p7= p6.parentNode;
let p8= p7.parentNode;// elemento padre 8 elementos arriba
```

Esto ultimo no lo considero una buena solución. Agradezco de antemano la ayuda,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C**uando trabajamos con programación estructurada, encontramos tareas repetitivas que nos agobian puesto que la programación es casi el 100% facilitar tareas.

para ello debemos abocarnos a mejorar el correcto uso del lenguaje creando nuestras propias formas de simplificar la tarea que estamos llevando a cabo.

```js
// usando parentnode n pasos apartir de object
function getParent(obj,n){for(let j=0;j<n;j++){obj=obj.parentNode;}return obj;}

let btn=document.getElementById("boton");
let padre8=getParent(btn,8);
console.log(padre8.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div>1
  <div>2
  <div>3
  <div>4
  <div>5
  <div>6
  <div>7
  <div>8
  <button id="boton">boton</button>
  <div>9
  <div>10
  </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

en el ejemplo se puede ver el uso de la función:

```
function getParent(obj,n){
  for(let j=0;j<n;j++){
    obj=obj.parentNode;
  }
return obj;
}
```

de modo minimalista

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo accediendo a el path que devuelve un arreglo con los elemento es forma ascedente en el doom donde el elemento seleccionado es el 0 de hay subes la cantidad que deses.

## ejemplo:

```js
document.querySelector("h3").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      console.log(e.path[8],e.path[8].id)
})
```

```html
<div id="8">
    <div id="7">
        <div id="6">
            <div id="5">
                <div id="4">
                    <div id="3">
                        <div id="2">
                            <div id="1">
                                    <h3>click</h3>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: este metodo es sencillo, pero el problema es que solo puedes usar path escuchando un evento.